# dragenter event firing more than once when dragged over parent element

Tags: javascript, drag

I'm working on a drag-and-drop list in javascript. If you drag over the last item in the list, it will create a new element below it more than once, like this:

[image]

How do I make it so that when it's dragged over the last item, it will only create one element below?

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/DumbMathBoy/4z5xtbga/8/

HTML:

```
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li draggable="true" data-value="1">1</li>
    <li draggable="true" data-value="2">2</li>
    <li draggable="true" data-value="3">3</li>
    <li draggable="true" data-value="4">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#list {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#list ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#list ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: thick solid white;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
#list ul li:hover {
    background: #444;
    cursor: move;
}

#list ul li.dragover {
    border-top: thick solid white;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.dragStartClass {
    opacity: 35%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#list ul li.dropzone {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background: none;
    border: 3px dashed #d00000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const list = document.getElementById('list');
let values = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
let array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < list.children[0].children.length; i++) {
    let getChildren = list.children[0].children[i].textContent;
    let getValues = getChildren;
    array.push(getValues);
}

function startDrag(event) {
    event.target.classList.add("dragStartClass");
    event.dataTransfer.setData('dragPoint', event.target.attributes['data-value'].nodeValue);
    event.dataTransfer.setData('ID', event.target.id);
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
}

function drag(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
function dragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
function dragEnter(event) {
        event.target.classList.add("dragover");

        if (event.target.attributes['data-value'] != null) {
            const newNode = document.createElement('li');
            newNode.className = 'dropzone';
            const dropVar = event.target.attributes['data-value'].nodeValue;
            const dropP = document.querySelectorAll("[data-value='" + dropVar + "']")[0];

            if (dropVar < values.length) {
                dropP.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, dropP);
            }  else if (parseInt(dropVar) == values.length) {
              dropP.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newNode);
            } else {
          
            }
        }
}

function dragLeave(event) {
        event.target.classList.remove("dragover");
    
        if (event.target.classList.contains("dropzone")) {
            const getNode = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');
            for (i = 0; i < getNode.length; i++) {
                console.log(getNode);
                getNode[i].remove();
            }
        }
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

}

document.addEventListener('dragstart', startDrag);
document.addEventListener('drag', drag);
document.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
document.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
document.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
document.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
document.addEventListener('drop', drop);
```